# Calculate adherence using proportion

Tags: ratio

My task is to calculate adherence of people.

If $0$ minutes = $100\%$;

$9600$ minutes = $0\%$;

what are $480$ minutes equal to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: How many lots of $480$ do you have to use to get to $9600$?

Comment: Thank you, I just realised how stupid my question was.